Using docker image redislabs/rejson won't respond to JSON calls when persistence is enabled
Not only is this weird, I'm probably missing something obvious.  If I launch the image with this command:
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name redis-redisjson --rm redislabs/rejson:latest
the container works perfectly and will respond to all commands.  However if I launch it with the --save parameter like so:
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name redis-redisjson --rm redislabs/rejson:latest --save 60 1 --loglevel warning
It will respond to a normal get command but when I use json.get it says command unrecognized, as if the json module won't load when there's persistence.
Wondering if someone has a clue.

https://hub.docker.com/r/redislabs/rejson/ is deprecated. You should use either Redis  Stack (https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack) or the latest pre-release version of Redis 8 (https://hub.docker.com/_/redis). Both include JSON.

I think you need to tell the server to load the module, probably a conflict between the conf file the server create and load from.
Try to create a redis.conf with loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so or symply pass --loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so when you launch.
